# How to add in Hashmap

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap

```
for (Object propNameObject : map.keySet()) {
            count++;
            String propertyName = (String) propNameObject;
            Object property1 = propUtils.getProperty(oldObject, propertyName);
            Object property2 = propUtils.getProperty(newObject, propertyName);
```

how can i add it in map for propNameObject is My key and for that key values are property1 and property2

Example:

```
     **name**:a[0]pradeep
              a[1]vijay`
      Noofdays:a[0]25`
               a[1]27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
// this map will have the required values
Map<String, List<Object>> newMap = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();

for (Object propNameObject : map.keySet()) {
    count++;
    String propertyName = (String) propNameObject;
    Object property1 = propUtils.getProperty(oldObject, propertyName);
    Object property2 = propUtils.getProperty(newObject, propertyName);
    List<Object> tempList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    tempList.add(property1);
    tempList.add(property2);
    newMap.put(propertyName, tempList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than 2 properties of different datatypes a better way of structuring your code will be for an instance

property 1 - String

property 2- Integer

you can also create a class of your properties & add to the map with the key

```
class Property 
{
String propertyOne;
Integer propertyTwo;

Property()
{
this.propertyOne=propertyOne;
this.propertyTwo=propertyTwo;
}

getters & setters;

}
```

& save it in the Map as

```
Map<String, Property> map= new HashMap<String, Property>();
map.put(propNameObject, new Property(property1, property2));
```